# jQuery jPlayer play remote url: "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden"

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I am using jQuery jPlayer circular skin on my site to play remote urls, the following code works just fine, except if the url is from a particular domain, (call it http://prob.lem), I am always getting `"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://prob.lem/upload_music/7154816.mp3"`, although I have no problem to either use a browser, or use wget, to download the mp3. My knowledge on jQuery is limited, my best guess it that the jQuery jPlayer sends the request differently than usual browser or wget (wrong?), the other detects it and refuse to serve the content.

The question is: assuming I guessed right, is there a work around from my site that my jPlayer still gets the content? if my guess was wrong, where else I should look at? 
Thanks,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){

var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
mp3: "http://prob.lem/upload_music/7154816.mp3"
}, {
cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
supplied: "mp3",
swfPath: "wp-content/plugins/magic-media-box/js/Jplayer.swf",
wmode: "window",
keyEnabled: true,

});
});

//]]>

</script>
```

Also, below is the request information from firebug:

```
Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2013 20:24:25 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 291
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Request Headers
GET /upload_music/7154816.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: prob.lem
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: audio/webm,audio/ogg,audio/wav,audio/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,video/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Range: bytes=0-
Referer: http://my.site/index.php/category/ktv/
Connection: keep-alive
```

If I open the link directly in firefox, the request information does look different:

```
Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2013 20:34:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sun, 21 Jul 2013 23:05:06 GMT
Etag: "1b2803e-b5ffef-4e20d97386aba"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 11927535
Connection: close
Content-Type: audio/mpeg

Request Headers
GET /upload_music/7154816.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: prob.lem
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

What I can see is that in the Request Headers, the `Accept` and `Accept-Encoding` string are different, and hence the responses are different. Can I let jQuery jPlayer to send the identical Headers as with the Firefox browser?

Thanks,

Comment: Check http://prob.lem/robots.txt for a possible user-agent disallowed (I'm not sure if you can block flash players with robots, but this is the first thing that came to my head)

Comment: @trojansdestroy thanks, prob.lem/robots.txt  i've updated the original question with more information.